# Laravel 5.1 Session store not set on request. at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:411

Tags: session, migration, laravel-5.1, scheduler, middleware

I have got this exception while running the following command

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

I have already added in middleware too

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

The exception is,

> Session store not set on request. {"exception":"[object]
>   (RuntimeException(code: 0): Session store not set on request. at
>   /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:411)

Comment: witch laravel you are using ??

Comment: I have using Laravel 5.1

Comment: OK, did you have all of your routes inside a group with web middleware ?? like this `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});` !!